# Visual Studio Explorer has suddenly started frequent crashing. Why?

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Stuido 2013 Pro with Team System. I'm running it as Administrator.

It has suddenly (this week) taken to crashing and restarting many times a day. It doesn't matter which of several solutions I am working on at the time. Most reliable (but not the only) way of provoking this is to close the currently open solution. Bang!

I've deleted all the solution *suo files (somebody previously pointed the finger at them) with no improvement.

Here are the error messages that appear in the Windows Event log:

First error message:

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Next Error message:

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.40629.0, time stamp: 0x5590c8a4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18939, time stamp: 0x55afd8e7
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x9e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d12376d7bd8425
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 257b845b-8f6a-11e5-9d42-e02a82c9f209

The VS  log file ActivityLog.xml shows one error message:

660 ERROR Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK...
          C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\

Given that this has appeared out of the blue, I'm guessing that there is some common file dynamically maintained by VS that has become corrupted, but I have no idea what that might be. Can anyone suggest what I can do about this?

TIA.

---

Oh dear - to do a repair took over an hour, and stalled at about 98% complete (I waited for 30 minutes at that point before cancelling). I then tried uninstalling - no success. I then downloaded and reinstalled Team Explorer then did a further repair for VS2013. Then it wouldn't start at all. The activity log has this at the end:

```
Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}  VisualStudio 2015/11/20 12:27:35.505 
57 ERROR CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C} 80131604 VisualStudio 2015/11/20 12:27:35.575 
58 ERROR End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio 2015/11/20 12:27:35.575 
59 Warning Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip flag {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}  VisualStudio 2015/11/20 12:27:35.575 
60 ERROR Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{99b8fa2f-ab90-4f57-9c32-949f146f1914} Frame caption: Source Control Explorer Exception details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

*Finally* after several attempts I managed to do a clean uninstall and a fresh reinstall (from the original ISO, followed by Update 5). However the original problem remains - every time I close a solution (any solution) VS2013 crashes and automatically restarts.

I seem to be up the creek without a paddle. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Have you tried repairing your VS with the installer? i.e. go into "Control Panel"->"Programs and Features".

Comment: Next step, but I speculated that a more likely cause was some file being messed up rather than code corruption.

Comment: Andrew Morton, see results of a repair in the amended question above.

Comment: You didn't mention if you'd tried using the [/SafeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) command line switch to start Visual Studio in safe mode.

Comment: If I use safe mode (as Administrator), I get this: An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged <snip>......

Exception details:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

Comment: Did this start to happen after the latest Windows updates? Do you have any [MSDN technical support incidents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266240.aspx)?

Comment: Possibly, and no - we don't have an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that I had previously downloaded and installed (from the Redgate Software website) their .Net Reflector tool, which had (by the by) also installed an extension for Visual Studio 2013. Today I uninstalled that extension and Visual Studio 2013 immediately began behaving again. I am recording this in case anyone else experiences the same issue with VS2013 crashing whenever they close an open solution.